# Glide,coil not loading images in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, sdk

in my application when i use real device every thing working as expected and the images is loaded successfully using glide but in emulator all the images fail to load.

here is what i tried:

**check internet connection**

**try emulator with sdk 28 and 30**

one of the images that i load:
https://trueexpress-s3.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/small_21305742044_air_freshener_liquid_beads_from_air_fresh_224849_7128b27d67.jpg

here is how i load images with glide:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.setImageUrl(url: String?) {
    if (url == null) {
        setImageBitmap(null)
        return
    }
    GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(url).into(this)
}
```

Screen shots:

[image]

[image]

EDIT MY LOGS:

```
2021-08-26 09:14:45.045 5274-5274/com.trends.trueexpress.debug W/Glide: Load failed for https://trueexpress-s3.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Untitled_1_copy_a514f5ee8a.jpg with size [532x300]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

Comment: Share your log-cat details

Answer (score 0):

add the code for glide section.

post the image url. hope image url is https not http.

try the below code and check for exception.

```
Glide.with(context).
        load(url)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .crossFade(1000)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: try to replace your glide code with mine above and print the Exception.  it will show the detailed cause. btw which version of glide you are using? latest version?

Comment: Yes it is and i tried this no exception thrown  ... i know this is crazy but when i try to run the same emulator with android 4.2.2 every thing work as expected!!!

Comment: add you gradle code. try adding a logged in onResourceReady?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added internet permission in manifest file?